# Selenium Webdriver Chrome creating to many Threads

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, apscheduler

i'm having some trouble about this WallBoard webapp (Python) that i have to fix, i hope i can be very clear of what the problem is so its easy for you to understand and help me.

So, the app has 3 pages, Main Page, Calls Waiting, Tickets. It is used by support team in this company to track calls of the day and tickets too.

So when i run this app with VS Code, its behavior is absolutely normal. App logs to another website to retrieve calls information, and Database to retrieve Tickets information. After some time session expires (retrieving calls information) but app detects and logs in again.

When i start the app at IIS(8.5) EVERY 17min the app gets restarted for no reason, and after a few hours of this i have 40 to 50 Google Chrome Threads taking all my memory from the machine it is hosted in...

I don't believe it is a problem with IIS, i think it is responding like this for some reason and i can't find out.

Here is the code for the WallBoard App

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, g, render_template
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pypyodbc as pyodbc
import time
import sys, socket
from funcs import *
from config import *
from querys import *
from cachetools import LRUCache
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

# Init
app = Flask(__name__)

app.debug = True


# Globals
CALLS_WAITING_CACHE = LRUCache(maxsize=20)
TICKETS_CACHE = LRUCache(maxsize=20)
op = Options()
op.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
op.add_argument("--headless")
op.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=op, executable_path=r'C:\Python34\Scripts\chromedriver.exe')

with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
    print('Walboard Starting! - ' + str(datetime.now()), file=f)


def login():

# Here i log in to the website where i get calls information

###################################################################


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    """Before Request"""

    g.request_start_time = time.time()
    g.request_time = lambda: "%.5f" % (time.time() - g.request_start_time)

####################################################################


@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Landing Page"""
    return render_template("landing.html",
                           dashboard_name='TSU WallBoard',
                           css_folder='/static/css/',
                           CallsWaiting_Page='/callswaiting',
                           Tickets_Page='/tickets'
                           )

####################################################################


def calls_waiting():
  #  Here i take the information and store in in cache thanks to cachetools

   ############################################################################


@app.route('/callswaiting')
def calls_wainting_render():
    # Here i take information from cache and show it in the webpage of the app


####################################################################


def tickets():
    # Here i do the same with tickets, load from DB and store in cache

@app.route('/tickets')
def tickets_render():
    # Here i load tickets from cache and show them in Web Page

##########################################################

# Login to avaya website
login()
time.sleep(3)
# Get calls and store in cache
calls_waiting()
# Get tickets and store in cache
tickets()

# Create scheduler obj
sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
# Create Jobs
sched.add_job(calls_waiting, 'interval', seconds=refresh_time_calls,
              max_instances=1, id='calls_waiting')
sched.add_job(tickets, 'interval', seconds=refresh_time_tickets,
              max_instances=1, id='tickets')
# Start scheduler              
sched.start()

with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
    print('WallBoard Started! - ' + str(datetime.now()), file=f)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run()
```

So at this point i'm completely lost, i have done hours of research trying to find what the problem is but still no luck.
I took out the code inside because it was too big but if necessary i can provide it.
I was using PhantomJS but i was always getting the Warning that is deprecated and i decided to change do ChromeDrive but the problem still remains.
Can it be with BackgroundScheduler? because i'm starting to think that each time IIS force the app to restart, it creates more Jobs and doesn't kill the others.

I appreciate all the help and tips, and i am really sorry for this long post!

[image]

I took this screenShot after 10min of running, i will update with new one in the morning

Comment: So i still have no idea why this is happening, but a workaround i found is to force IIS to recycle this application every 15min and it kills all the extra Threads running and starts only the ones need to run. It would be great if someone could explain to me why this happens :(